# Proper approach of listening solidity events in NestJS

Tags: events, nestjs, solidity

I am developing dApp. I am using NestJS and I have written contracts in solidity.

There are few events emitted from solidity. I need to listen to those events in NestJS.
My code to listen to solidity events is

```
contract.on('EventName', async(val, event)=>{
// do something
})
```

What is the appropriate way to listen to events in NestJS?
Right now I am trying to place event listening code in `onModuleInit` but wanted to confirm if there are any other better approach to do this.